# How to restrict a tuple?

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

I think tuples in Haskell are like

```
  tuple :: (a,b)
```

which means a and b can be the same type or can be diffrent types

so if i define a function without giving the type for it then i will get probably (t,t1) or some diffrent types when i write :t function in ghci.
So is it possible to get only the same types without defining it in function.
I heard its not allowed in haskell

so i cant write some function like

```
  function [(x,x)]=[(x,x,x)]
```

to get the

```
  :t function
     function :: [(a,a)]->[(a,a,a)]
```

This is an exercise that i am trying to do and this exercise want me to write a function without defining a type.For example to get

```
  Bool->(Char,Bool)
```

when i give

```
  :t function
```

in ghci. i should ve write--

```
  function True=('A',True)
```

i am not allowed to define the type part of a function
So i cant write

```
  function::(Eq a)=>[(a,a)]->[(a,a,a)]
```

or something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `asTypeOf` from the Prelude to restrict the type of the second component of your tuple to be the same as the type of the first component. For example, in GHCi:

```
> let f (x, y) = (x, y `asTypeOf` x, x)

> :t f
f :: (t, t) -> (t, t, t)
```

Comment: is there a any possible way to rename the 't' with 'a' ?

Comment: No, as types are equal up to alpha-conversion, `(t, t) -> (t, t, t)` is really the same `(a, a) -> (a, a, a)`; how GHC renders that type is really a detail of the implementation of the compiler and beyond your control.

Answer (score 4):

You can happily restrict the types to be equivalent .. by writing out the required type.

```
type Pair a = (a,a)
type Triple a = (a,a,a)
```

and then:

```
fn :: [Pair a] -> [Triple a]
```

will enforce the constraint you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think you got me wrong.This is an exercise that i am trying to do and this exercise want me to write a function without defining a type.For example to get Bool->(Char,Bool) when i give :t function in ghci.
i should ve write-- function True=('A',True).i am not allowed to define the type part of a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `type`, as Don says. Or, if you don't want to bother with that (perhaps you only need it for one function), you can specify the type signature of the function like this:

```
function :: [(a,a)] -> [(a,a,a)]
function xs = map (\(a, b) -> (a, b, a)) xs -- just an example
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is the [**`asTypeOf`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aasTypeOf) function. Using it you can restrict a type of some value to be the same as the one of another value in the function definition. E.g.:

```
Prelude> :t \(a, b) -> (a, b `asTypeOf` a)
\(a, b) -> (a, b `asTypeOf` a) :: (t, t) -> (t, t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work without `asTypeOf`:

```
trans (a,b) = case [a,b] of _ -> (a,b,a)
function xs = map trans xs
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, if I've understood this correctly, the problem you're having really has nothing to do with types. Your definition,

```
function [(x,x)]=[(x,x,x)]
```

won't work because you're saying, in effect, "if the argument to 
`function` is a list with one element, and that element is a tuple,
then call then bind `x` to the first part of the tuple *and* also bind
`x` to the second part of the tuple".
You can't bind a symbol to two expressions at once.

If what you really want is to ensure that both parts of the tuple
are the same, then you can do something like this:

```
function [(x,y)] = if x == y then [(x,x,x)] else error "mismatch"
```

or this:

```
function2 [(x,y)] | x == y = [(x,x,x)]
```

...but that will fail when the parts of the tuple don't match.

Now I suspect what you really want is to handle lists with more than
one element. So you might want to do something like:

```
function3 xs = map f xs
  where f (x, y) = if x == y then [(x,x,x)] else error "mismatch"
```

Any of these functions will have the type you want, `Eq t => [(t, t)] -> [(t, t, t)]` without you having to specify it.